# Alt key codes – 2 digits vs 3 digits

Tags: keyboard, alt-code

Open up Notepad and type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> and this give a character ►
But when I type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> I don’t get any character.

What’s the difference here?

When I type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> I get ß
When I type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>225225</kbd> I get ╔ which corresponds to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>201</kbd>

How is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>225225</kbd> the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>201</kbd>?

Comment: I avoid the question of different numbers of digits returning different by always entering 4 digits. Alt + Numpad0 + Numpad0 + Numpad1 + Numpad6.

Answer (score 5):

The reason that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num16</kbd> gives you ►, while <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num016</kbd> gives you nothing, is so you can access both the characters that are mapped to codes 1 through 31 by [IBM PC code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) and the control characters in that range of [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). You enter a leading zero for the control characters and omit leading zeros for the graphic characters in this set: ☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○◙♂♀♪♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼

To give this a try, you can type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num9</kbd> for ○ (circle) or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num09</kbd> for <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num13</kbd> for ♪ or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num013</kbd> for <kbd>Return</kbd>. Let's just say that the use for ASCII 16 (Ctrl-P) is [lost in the mists of time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes).

If you are using a Unicode-compatible application such as Wordpad, entering <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num225225</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num28617</kbd> (225225 % 65536 = 28617) which is character U+6FC9 or 濉

Comment: actually the 0-prefix codes are for the Windows-1252 characterset, which is a superset of ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

225225 % 256 = 201

Or, the binary representation of 225225 ends in the binary representation of 201.